# Why Firefox doesnt work with split DNS / Host Overrides?

Tags: internal-dns, firefox, split-dns

I have configured Host overrides in pfSense and other browsers like Chrome and Edge work fine but Firefox simply does not resolve giving "Unable to connect" error.

This is the same on my laptop with fresh install of Firefox with default settings. DNS over HTTPS is disabled by default so that's not it.

Why is Firefox not working with Split DNS? I would like to continue using Firefox but if there is no solution to this its a useless browser to me. Any help appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: How about a screenshot of the [relevant Firefox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdMvM.png)?

Comment: They are default, out of the fox settings, I even tried booting Ubuntu Live image. I also would have no idea which settings would be relevant apart from DNS over SSL.

Comment: OK, so where is the screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot of what? There are pages and pages of settings in Firefox...

Comment: Yes, and my own screenshot showed you exactly which one and how to get to it. Click the link.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Missed the link completely. My settings are identical to yours. It was "Use system proxy settings" by default but same with "No proxy". DNS over HTTPS was always disabled.

Comment: Time to look at the computer, then. What are its resolver settings? i.e. `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Its not the computer settings. Its the same issue on My Windows desktop, laptop and even live Ubuntu image. All browsers work except Firefox. Its an issue with Firefox as everything else was ruled out.